# Can I modify the attribute of an input stored in an array?

Tags: jquery

Here is my html

```
<form id="emailForm">
        <div class="textbox">
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Nouvelle adresse e-mail">
          <span class="check-message hidden">REQUIS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="textbox">
           <input type="text" id="code" name="code" placeholder="Rentrez le code reçu">
           <span class="check-message hidden">REQUIS</span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirmer" class="login-btn" disabled>
      </form>
```

and my jquery

```
$("#emailForm .textbox input").keydown(function() {
      var inputs = $("#emailForm .textbox input");
        if (inputs[0].value != "") {
          inputs[1].attr("disabled", true);
          inputs[1].addClass("disabled");
        } else if (inputs[1].value != "") {
          inputs[0].attr("disabled", true);
          inputs[0].addClass("disabled");
        } else if (inputs[0].value != "" && inputs[1].value) {
          inputs[0].attr("disabled", false);
          inputs[0].removeClass("disabled");
          inputs[1].attr("disabled", false);
          inputs[1].removeClass("disabled");
        }
    });
```

I want to disable an input when the user types in the other one.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: I am not getting this properly. What is the issue that you are facing here?

Comment: It seems that I can't access the attribute of an input when it's in an array. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is `inputs[0]` & `inputs[1]` here are DOM elements and not jQuery objects and all the jquery methods like `.attr()`, `.addClass()` can only be use on jQuery objects, not on the DOM elements. You can fix this by using [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get elements as jQuery objects like:

```
var input1 = inputs.eq(0);
var input2 = inputs.eq(1);
```

Then you can use all jquery methods on `input1` and `input2` without any issues.

**Demo:**

```js
$("#emailForm .textbox input").keydown(function() {
  var inputs = $("#emailForm .textbox input");
  
  var input1 = inputs.eq(0);
  var input2 = inputs.eq(1);
  
  if (input1.val() != "") {
    input2.attr("disabled", true);
    input2.addClass("disabled");
  } else if (input2.val() != "") {
    input1.attr("disabled", true);
    input1.addClass("disabled");
  } else if (input1.val() == "" || input2.val() == "") {
    input1.attr("disabled", false);
    input1.removeClass("disabled");
    input2.attr("disabled", false);
    input2.removeClass("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="emailForm">
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Nouvelle adresse e-mail">
    <span class="check-message hidden">REQUIS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="text" id="code" name="code" placeholder="Rentrez le code reçu">
    <span class="check-message hidden">REQUIS</span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Confirmer" class="login-btn" disabled>
</form>
```